# Execute php script with arguments from another php file

Tags: php

I'm playing with a script that I had to call from another php file. From file `update.php`, at the beginning I have to start the script by calling its file `serv.php`. But, in order for `serv.php` to work I had to pass a couple of arguments. The command to start `serv.php` from command line is as follow:

`php c:\path_to_folder\serv.php run --argument1="some_text" --argument2="some_text" --port=some_port`

If we presume that `update.php` and `serv.php` are at the same folder, how to call `serv.php` from within `update.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Send $argv of serv.php from serv.php to update.php (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php). I.e. in update.php you will have another $argv, so you have to send list of command line parameters in array with different name.

Answer (score 0):

use `exec` or `system` call within your calling PHP Script. do mention full path of PHP CLI i.e. /user/bin/php or whatever path is there in your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a system command using the `exec` function. [PHP exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

You can call your page `serv.php` from your `update.php` script as such

```
exec('php c:\path_to_folder\serv.php run --argument1="some_text" --argument2="some_text" --port=some_port');
```

Comment: `exec('php c:\inetpub\wwwroot\update\server.php --argument1="some_text" --argument2="some_text" --port=some_port');`

that doesn't work. `shell_exec` also.

Comment: what errors do you get? do you have error_reporting on? any indication of what's wrong at all?

Comment: OK. I'm 100% sure that `exec('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe "php c:\path_to_file\serv.php run --arg1="some_text" --arg2="some_text" --port=some_port"');` starts `cmd.exe`. So what's left is how to pass the starting statement `php c:\path_to_file\serv.php run --arg1="some_text" --arg2="some_text" --port=some_port` to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_exec("php c:\path_to_folder\serv.php some_text some_text some_port ");
```

usually is `php -f` or `php5-cli` instead of `php` and some servers don't even require the path to the php folder
This is one of my query:

```
$ex=$setting[8]." ".dirname(__FILE__)."/sendmail.php NewMem ".$_SESSION['id']." ";
if(substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows")
    pclose(popen("start /B ".$ex,"r")); /windows server
else
    shell_exec($ex." > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");//Apache
```

where `$setting[8]` is `php -f` or `php5-cli`, `".dirname(__FILE__)."/sendmail.php` is the path to the file, and the others are the arguments .
 
To retrieve the passed arguments use `$argv` that contains all the other parameter `$argv[0]` is the file path.
Note that each space define a new argument